# Is possibile to open a PDF in SwiftUI using Quicklook?

Tags: pdf, swiftui, quicklook

I am developing an application that integrates a button that must refer to display a pdf file. Is it possible to do this using QuickLook?

Best Regards,
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

here's some sample code.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
struct PreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
     
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        return navigationController
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {}
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDelegate, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        let parent: PreviewController
        init(parent: PreviewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
    }
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            return parent.url as NSURL
        }
    }
}
```